# My EditText is only updated by SetText(); every 2nd attempt

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, settext

I'm trying to display date and time in an EditText box and have made some code here. The thing is, it's working - but only on the second attempt. Meaning I select date and time.. Nothing happens and on the second try the setText(); updates the EditText to display date and time. However, as you might have guessed, I'd like it to update the EditText immediately.

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reservation);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    textViewUserid = findViewById(R.id.addReservation_userId_edittext);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    textViewUserid.setText(user.getEmail());

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);

    mDisplayDate = findViewById(R.id.addReservation_fromTime_edittext);
    mDisplayDate2 = findViewById(R.id.addReservation_toTime_edittext);


    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    AddReservationActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Light,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    year,month,day);

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                    AddReservationActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Light,
                    mTimeSetListener,
                    hour,minute,true);

            timePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            timePickerDialog.show();
            datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month + 1;
            final String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;

            mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    if (minute < 10) {
                        String time = "" + hourOfDay + ":" + "0"+minute;
                        mDisplayDate.getText().toString();
                        mDisplayDate.setText(date + " " + time);
                    }else {
                        String time = "" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
                        mDisplayDate.getText().toString();
                        mDisplayDate.setText(date + " " + time);

                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

I've been trying for some hours now to fix this, looking all over Stackoverflow and numerous other sites. This is mildly frustrating and I really hope someone has an input on what I'm doing wrong.

Apologies if there's somehow already a solution on the site I've missed.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you pasted. Is `mTimeSetListener` supposed to be inside `mDateSetListener`? Then you also have some weird `onCreate()` at the bottom. Try pasting your code again.

Comment: @TheWanderer should be fixed now. The idea was to have the EditText contain both the date AND time. Therefore, I put  mTimeSetListener and mDateSetListener together. I'm relatively new to android, so this might overall be a bad solution. Thanks

Comment: `mTimeSetListener` shouldn't be set only when a date is set. Set it once, like with `mDateSetListener`. Then you can append the time to the EditText after setting the date string to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, appending the EditText - as suggested in a comment. So instead of trying to set the text of the EditText with both the date and time string simultaneously. I seperated them and made a setText(date); and append with time:

```
  mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month + 1;
            final String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        }
    };
    mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            if (minute < 10) {
                String time = " " + hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
                mDisplayDate.append(time);
            } else {
                String time = " " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
                mDisplayDate.append(time);

            }
        }
    };
```